# Count the maximum number of side-by-side letter with Ruby

Tags: ruby, regex, string

how can we get the maximum number of letters that are side-by-side?

For example, if we count every side by side maximum letters `a`:

```
"Muhahaha, hello world!!!!! Aaaaaaaa" # => 7
"fuu" # => 0
"foobar" # => 1
"aaa bbb ccc" # => 3
"aa bb cc aaaaa ff" # => 5
```

I'm using Ruby 1.9.3.  According to the String class, I don't think there's already a method that can do this stuff.  Maybe the Regexp class could be more useful.

Do you think there's a sexy way to do it?  Thank for any suggestions.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

My way is:

```
"Muhahaha, hello world!!!!! Aaaaaaaa".scan(/a+/).max.length #=> 7
```

or if that will not work then (but it should)

```
"Muhahaha, hello world!!!!! Aaaaaaaa".scan(/a+/).sort.last.length #=> 7
```

Comment: if we want to generalize ? making this working with any letter?

Comment: @Hauleth I think Jeremy is looking for `letter = 'a'; "Muhahaha, helloooo world!!!!! Aaaaaaaa".scan(/#{letter}+/).max.length`.

Answer (score 1):

```
# returns the longest stretch of the same word character
str = "Muhahaha, hello world!!!!! Aaaaaaaa"
str.scan(/\w/).to_set.map { |c| str.scan(/#{c}+/).max }.sort_by(&:length).last.length
```